# XMPP/AMQP/Websockets vs Pusher/Beacon push?

Tags: streaming, xmpp, chat, websocket, amqp

With Pusher and Beacon push cloud services I can get live updates in all browsers. Even implement chat functionality.

Can't these cloud services replace the need of me learning XMPP/AMQP/Websockets/Comet to implement the same kind of live updates/feeds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These services offer Infrastructure as a Service so that you don't have to worry about the underlying technology. That said the services do use the technology as a selling point e.g. Pusher very much use WebSockets to sell their service.

As well as [Pusher](https://pusher.com) there are similar services so I'd recommend checking out the [real-time tech guide](https://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide/) for others that haven't been mentioned (I work for Pusher).

> Can't these cloud services replace the need of me learning XMPP/AMQP/Websockets/Comet to implement the same kind of live updates/feeds?

Yes. The point in these frameworks and services is to abstract away the underlying connection and protocols to provide you with a reasonable real-time communication pattern (simple messaging, pub-sub, evented pub-sub, RPC/RMI or DataSync) that works for the application functionality that you are looking to build.